# Does Z3py support "String" and "Sequence"

Tags: sequence, z3py

In Z3, it supports String and Sequence. But does Z3py supports them as well, or we have to use string or list from Python? From the latest release, it seemed that the new version did support the theories of String and Sequence, but I don't know how to use it. Would anyone give me an example about sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Z3 supports strings and sequences, but there is only rudimentary support in the last public release. You'll have to compile the latest master from source to get all of the features (which includes the Python API).

Comment: @jonnor just search stackoverflow for z3 and string, many examples have been posted in questions and answers over the past couple of years.